# Xcode iOS testsuite NSLog output missing

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, output

I'm developing an iOS app using Xcode 6 and am trying to run a test suite in Xcode. I can run the test but I don't see where my `NSLog` statements output. They are not in the output panel.

How do I find the output?

```
@interface ISTest : XCTestCase
@end

@implement ISTest
- (void) setUp {
    [super setUp];
}

- (void) tearDown {
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void) testExample {
    NSLog(@"Where does this go???");
}

- (void) testPerformanceExample {
    [self measureBlock^{
    }];
}
@end
```

Comment: All log statements should appear in the debugging area.  Can you post an example test case?

Comment: @JAL Where is the debugging area?

Comment: The debugging area is the lower view in Xcode that shows the console and the variables in scope when you hit a breakpoint.  Make sure this view is open by clicking the square button with the blue rectangle on the bottom in the top-right corner of Xcode.

Comment: Somehow, I can see the output in All Output now... Don't know what happened before.... Thanks.

Comment: I have added my answer below.  Feel free to mark it as accepted if it helped you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check console in the debugging area (the lower view) in Xcode.  To open this view, click the square button with the blue rectangle on the bottom in the top-right corner of Xcode.

Edit: Why the downvote?  Log statements appear in the debugging area for me.

Test:

```
- (void)testLoginViewControllerViewExists {
    NSLog(@"Testing Login View Controller");
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
    CSLoginViewController *loginVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:
                                      @"loginVC"];
    XCTAssertNotNil([loginVC view], @"loginVC should contain a view");
}
```

Output:

```
Test Case '-[AppTests testLoginViewControllerViewExists]' started.
2014-11-06 15:52:00.175 App[14870:2071450] Testing Login View Controller
Test Case '-[AppTests testLoginViewControllerViewExists]' passed (0.001 seconds).
```

Comment: Make sure that async is handled correctly otherwise any NSLog's in a completion block won't output.

Comment: The OP is looking for the NSLog() statements within his application, not the test code.  What you'd normally see when running a debug, not test.

Answer (score 5):

Log output in tests does not go to the console.

If you want to see your logs, they are in the build output.

Comment: The NSLog() output from within the app code is not there.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see your messages or your strings in your tests being printed on the output console use `printf` and not `NSLog`

Example: `printf("%s", [yourNSString UTF8String]);`